# Can enableLocking be set dynamically on an Ext JS grid?

Tags: extjs

I am wondering whether it is possible to enable column locking on a grid dynamically at all?

I have a grid where I am able to rearrange columns dynamically when a button is pressed using `moveAfter`

```
    // Reorder columns
    grid.headerCt.suspendLayouts();
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      grid.headerCt.moveAfter(columns[i], (columns[i - 1] || null));
    }
    grid.headerCt.resumeLayouts(true);
```

However, if I set `enableLocking` on the grid to `true`, when I hit the button, all the columns disappear, but no error is actually raised, which makes the problem hard to troubleshoot. Therefore, I was thinking I could disable locking beforing moving the columns. Does anybody know whether one can do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try to reconfigure the grid with columns with the [`reconfigure`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked was to run the code above on the part of the grid that is not locked, that is

```
var normalGrid = grid.normalGrid;

// Reorder columns
normalGrid.headerCt.suspendLayouts();
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
   normalGrid.headerCt.moveAfter(columns[i], (columns[i - 1] || null));
}
normalGrid.headerCt.resumeLayouts(true);
```